# Is there a way to insert a camelcase table name in pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, quoted-identifier

I have a DB with table names written in underscore format. I want to edit their names and also to be able to name every new table in a camelcase format

Still, whenever I use a query to call a camelcase table name I have to do it using double quotes. I do not want double or single quotes. Only the table name. Is it possible?

I have found a similar post describing 3 possible options about naming a table **column** in pgAdmin not including what I am looking for.

Also, that was 6 years ago and I am wondering if some things have changed since then, while I have not found any solution yet.

Comment: "Is it possible?" In a word, no. You have to use quotes if you want case sensitivity. Bear in mind changing their names to camelCase would be going against the usual naming conventions.

Comment: i see , thank you .